# FileWriter not writing all string entered at user input

Tags: java

In my below FileWriter below, I am writing to a file called "employee.txt."
It writes to the file but originally it was only appending to the file vs going into a new line each time. I since then edited the code by adding "\n" to make it go down by a line. My issue is that despite adding or removing the "\n" from my code, it seems to only take the last input a user entered. For eg. if a user wants to enter 2 employees, it only enters the last employee name. See code below:

```
 static int addEmployee() throws IOException{
    int x;
    String y = null;
    Scanner emp_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter how many employees you want to add to file:\n ");
    x = emp_input.nextInt();

    for (int i=0; i<x;i++) {
    System.out.println("Add an employee name: ");
    y= emp_input.next();
    }

    try {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("employee.txt", true);
    fileWriter.write("\n");
    fileWriter.write(y);
    fileWriter.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Updated to printing out to screen to test output before writing to file:

```
    static int addEmployee() throws IOException{
        int x;
        String y = null;
        Scanner emp_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter how many employees you want to add to file:\n ");
        x = emp_input.nextInt();


        for (int i=0; i<x;i++) {
          System.out.println("Add an employee name: ");
          y= emp_input.next();
        }

        System.out.println(y);



        return 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you don't understand how loops and scope works! You **only** do one thing in the body of your loop, and that is asking for input! You ask for y 5 times, but when you don't do anything with that y within the loop, only the last input will stay. I slightly edited your code to make it clear to you what the scope of your loop is!

Comment: So please see my updates and try to work from there. This is really basic stuff. Step back, and closely look at your code. Each line, and each character matters, especially those that mark the end of the loop body!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create that file writer **after** the for loop. And: you are only writing that newline and that last *y* object to the file writer!

So: create the file writer *brfore* the loop, and then write each employee object to the same file writer instance during the loop body!

Bonus hint: use names that mean something (*y* does not, it only confuses your readers) and follow Java naming conventions.

Finally: you should research what the term "scope" means. Suggestion: don't declare your variables globally, try to declare them in the smallest meaningful scope!